# Page only shows up when you rotate screen in iOS

Tags: asp.net, ios, vb.net

I have a website that is written in ASP.NET and VB. When trying to view certain pages on an iOS device, the screen will load just blank, but when you rotate the screen all of the data appears. Why is it doing this and how do I make it so that it will load without having to rotate the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Force a screen update when the page is done loading. Something like follows:

```
 // Page loading code
 [yourWebView setNeedsDisplay]

 // Other code
```

Comment: Actually it seems to only load when rotated on its side, and once again disappears when rotated back vertically. But I don't think I have a web view? Like I said its an ASP.NET and VB site, not iOS.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood the question. Since you put the iOS tag, I thought you were trying to load the page in an app WebView

Comment: Sorry about that. I just meant that I'm trying to view the site on an iPad/iPhone, but it is written in ASP.Net and VB.

Comment: Sorry, I will delete my answer shortly as it has absolutely nothing to do with your problem, I would recommend updating your question to reflect the clarification

Comment: I actually tried loading the website using iOS7 beta for developers and it seems to fix this issue. I'm thinking its a problem of iframes not being able to load sometimes in iOS6.

Comment: maybe, I have no idea